# Executing SQL from Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2010 (ALTER TRIGGER, CREATE PROCEDURE etc)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, server-explorer

I am currently modifying a web application to use a MS SQL 2008 database with will be located in the app_data folder and auto-attached.  Everything is fine and I can connect to the database and query it from within the application and also Visual Studio.

Although I need to also create/update some triggers and stored procedures, which I can not do - every time I choose the 'Add new stored procedure' from the right click menu in Visual Studio's Server Explorer menu, it creates a new template but I am unable to execute it, as there are not options enabled on the 'Query Designer' tool bar.

Maybe I am doing something completely wrong, but surely it should be just a case of creating my stored procedure and then clicking an execute button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have never used Server Explorer for any database schema editing in Visual Studio and have previously only used SQL Server Management Studio, all I can say is that it is very unintuitive!

From within SQL Server Management studio, you create the procedure using the usual 'CREATE PROCEDURE' code and then execute it, if you happen to click the save button you are able to save a local copy as a .sql file, but doing so will not change anything within the database.

In Visual Studio's Server Explorer however, there is no way to execute any SQL, you can not execute any 'CREATE PROCEDURE', 'ALTER TRIGGER', etc.  If you want to make changes to an object you have to click save instead - which is certainly not what you would do from within SQL Management Studio!

Microsoft certainly don't make simple tasks easy!

Comment: How difficult is it, really, to simply switch over to SSMS and do the stored procedure there, if you find it more intuitive?

Answer (score 0):

Select the SQL that you want to run (CTRL + A to select all), then right-click on it and choose RUN SELECTION.  I can't, however, find any equivalent short-cut key.

Robert Harvey's answer was news to me, I admit, and is just weird.  You can only "save" a query which begins with the word CREATE, it appears - and it's contrary to every principle of SQL that you can do so!